# Копирование в буфер с сохранением форматирования

Tags: javascript

В общем поставили передо мной задачу, сделать на сайте кнопку, по нажатию на которую в буфер обмена копируется текст, да не просто текст, а табличка, пригодная для вставки в документы word.
Решение для первой части было найдено быстро https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard а вот со вставкой в документы возникла вполне естественная проблема. Текст копируется с тегами. Есть ли возможность преобразовать его в текст с форматированием для ворда?
Как должен выглядеть код который будет сохранён в буфере обмена?
С подобными задачами никогда не сталкивался, поэтому даже незнаю как правильно загуглить. Пните в нужную сторону, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ситуация немного прояснилась, для копирования в буфер c сохранением форматирования, необходимо установить вормат буфера в RTF, остаётся только узнать как это сделать

Comment: Чувак удачи. Сочевствую конечно, но интересно поглядеть как ты это реализуешь. Отпишись пажалуйста потом.

Comment: Должно помочь: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4854628/276994

Comment: В общем в связи c низким бюджетом проекта и горящими сроками решили задачу упростить, при нажатии на "скопировать в буфер" выделяется нужный объект и выводится сообщение c просьбой нажать CTRL+C. Решение простое и не совсем то что нужно было изначально. Возможно, в будущем ещё вернёмся к реализации.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, у меня все нормально копируется в word без тегов, с таблицей даже. Вот мой код:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){ //перехватываем событие при копировании
 e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', "<table><tr><td><b>1</b></td><td><b>2</b></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table>"); //устанавливаем свой текст в буфер обмена
 e.preventDefault(); //отключаем стандартную обработку события
});
```

Comment: А разве clipboardData в любом событии доступна? Вроде политика безопасности браузера доступ к этому свойству только в обработчике копирвоания предоставляет. Задача же сводится к заполнению буфера при клике по кнопке на сайте.

Comment: Если, через кнопку, то делать придется только через флеш, по другому никак, тут есть все для этого:
http://zeroclipboard.org/
Но я бы лично лучше рассмотрел вариант с "ctrl + c", вместо кнопки написать просто нажмите "ctrl + c", так гораздо проще получится :)

Comment: Ваша лодка готова, капитан=) Именно это я и написал в последнем комментарии к вопросу два года назад=)